# Is it possible to group and sum multiple columns with MongoDB's aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given this MongoDB collection:

```
[
  { character: 'broquaint', race: 'Halfling', class: 'Hunter' },
  { character: 'broquaint', race: 'Halfling', class: 'Hunter' },
  { character: 'broquaint', race: 'Halfling', class: 'Rogue' },
  { character: 'broquaint', race: 'Naga',     class: 'Fighter' },
  { character: 'broquaint', race: 'Naga',     class: 'Hunter' }
]
```

I would like to get a count of each race and class i.e

```
{
  race:  { 'Halfling': 3, 'Naga': 2 },
  class: { 'Hunter': 3, 'Rogue': 1, 'Fighter': 1 }
}
```

And I've been trying to do this using the aggregation framework (to
replace an existing map/reduce) but have only been able to get as far
as getting counts for the combinations i.e

```
{ '_id': { race: 'Halfling', class: 'Hunter' },  count: 2 }
{ '_id': { race: 'Halfling', class: 'Rogue' }    count: 1 }
{ '_id': { race: 'Naga',     class: 'Fighter' }, count: 1 }
{ '_id': { race: 'Naga',     class: 'Hunter' },  count: 1 }
```

Which is simple enough to reduce programmatically to the desired
result but I was hoping to be able to leave that to MongoDB.

For reference here's the code I have so far:

```
db.games.aggregate(
  { '$match': { character: 'broquaint' } },
  {
    '$group': {
      _id:   { race: '$race', background: '$background'},
      count: { '$sum': 1 }
    }
  }
)
```

So the question is - given that example collection can I arrive at my
desired output purely through MongoDB's aggregation framework?

For any help that might be rendered many thanks in advance!

Comment: what's "$background"?  class?

Comment: Sorry in that code it should read "class" instead of "background", the column name is actually "background" but I chose "class" for brevity I just failed at consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with aggregation framework.  It won't be pretty, but then it'll still be much faster than with mapreduce...

Here it is in a nutshell (output a different format than what you give but same content):

```
> group1 = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$race",
        "class" : {
            "$push" : "$class"
        },
        "count" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
};
> unwind = { "$unwind" : "$class" };
> group2 = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$class",
        "classCount" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        },
        "races" : {
            "$push" : {
                "race" : "$_id",
                "raceCount" : "$count"
            }
        }
    }
};
> unwind2 = { "$unwind" : "$races" };
> group3 ={
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "classes" : {
            "$addToSet" : {
                "class" : "$_id",
                "classCount" : "$classCount"
            }
        },
        "races" : {
            "$addToSet" : "$races"
        }
    }
};
> db.races.aggregate(group1, unwind, group2, unwind2, group3);
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "classes" : [
                {
                    "class" : "Fighter",
                    "classCount" : 1
                },
                {
                    "class" : "Hunter",
                    "classCount" : 3
                },
                {
                    "class" : "Rogue",
                    "classCount" : 1
                }
            ],
            "races" : [
                {
                    "race" : "Naga",
                    "raceCount" : 2
                },
                {
                    "race" : "Halfling",
                    "raceCount" : 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: there are different answers possible if you know the complete set of possible races and classes - in that case it's easy to generate exact format that you have in your question.

Comment: When I was finally ready to post an answer, I saw that you already did... and 40 minutes faster... and with two commands less. ;)

Comment: Just call me The Master of Aggregation Framework.  Er, I mean Mistress.  If it can be done with it ... I've probably done it.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much, @AsyaKamsky! Now I am left to the enviable task of understanding how it works :)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: It answers the question, but is that really a good idea?  It seems quite inefficient.  Is it not better practically-speaking to just run two simple $group aggregations?  And I can't imagine adding a 3rd or 4th value to the counts using this technique.

Comment: Is it a good idea or not depends on the requirements of the original author/use case.

Answer (score 3):

Since MongoDB 3.4 this can be achieved a bit simpler using multiple aggregation pipelines with `$facet`.

taken from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/):

> **$facet**
>
> Processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the
>   same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in
>   the output document where its results are stored as an array of
>   documents.

So, for your use case, this would be achieved by the following:

```
const aggregatorOpts = [
    { $match: { character: 'broquaint' } }, // Match the character
    {
        // Seperate into 2 or more pipes that will count class and
        // race seperatly
        $facet: {
            race: [
                // Group by race and get the count:
                // [
                //   {
                //     _id: 'Halfling',
                //     count: 3
                //   }
                //   {
                //     _id: 'Naga',
                //     count: 2
                //   }
                // ]

                // $sortByCount is the same as
                // { $group: { _id: <expression>, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
                // { $sort: { count: -1 } }

                { $sortByCount: '$race' },

                // Now we want to transform the array in to 1 document,
                // where the '_id' field is the key, and the 'count' is the value.
                // To achieve this we will use $arrayToObject. According the the
                // docs, we have to first rename the fields to 'k' for the key,
                // and 'v' for the value. We use $project for this:
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        k: '$_id',
                        v: '$count',
                    },
                },
            ],
            // Same as above but for class instead
            class: [
                { $sortByCount: '$class' },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        k: '$_id',
                        v: '$count',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        // Now apply the $arrayToObject for both class and race.
        $addFields: {
            // Will override the existing class and race arrays
            // with their respective object representation instead.
            class: { $arrayToObject: '$class' },
            race: { $arrayToObject: '$race' },
        },
    },
];

db.races.aggregate(aggregatorOpts)
```

Which produces the following:

```
[
  {
    "race": {
      "Halfling": 3,
      "Naga": 2
    },
    "class": {
      "Hunter": 3,
      "Rogue": 1,
      "Fighter": 1,
    }
  }
]
```

If you are happy with the output formatting provided @Asya, then you can remove the `$project`and `$addFields`stages, and just leave the `$sortByCount` part in each sub-pipeline.

With these new features, the aggregation is a lot easier to extend with additional counts,
Just add another aggregation pipeline in `$facet`.
It is even a bit easier to count sub groups, but that would be a separate question.